# How to get the Color profile of an Image using Applescript?

Tags: macos, applescript

)

I want to write an apple-script which collect the color profile of an image.. can anyone please help me out how to do this? I've no idea!!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To even potentially have a chance to come up with a decent answer, you need to edit your question to add more detail.  Applescript depends on the scripting dictionary offered by whatever application you're calling.  What application has this image open?  And would you be open to another way to get the color profile of your image than using AppleScript?  Is this for an application you are working on, yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like using [ExifTool by Phil Harvey](http://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) to extract metadata. Here is a [service I wrote](http://www.johneday.com/219/exiftool-service-for-quick-metadata-access) to access the metadata quickly.

```
on run {input, parameters}
    -- creates a metadata folder in the Documents folder to store results
    set thePath to POSIX path of (path to documents folder) & "metadata" & "/"
    do shell script "mkdir -p " & quoted form of POSIX path of thePath

    set {inputFiles, outputFiles} to {{}, {}}
    repeat with anItem in input
        set end of inputFiles to quoted form of POSIX path of (anItem as text)
        tell application "Finder" to set {name:fileName, name extension:nameExtension} to anItem
        set baseName to text 1 thru ((get offset of "." & nameExtension in fileName) - 1) of fileName
        set end of outputFiles to quoted form of (thePath & baseName & ".txt")
    end repeat

    set {TID, text item delimiters} to {text item delimiters, space}
    set {inputFiles, outputFiles} to {(inputFiles as text), (outputFiles as text)}
    set text item delimiters to TID

    do shell script "exiftool -a " & inputFiles & " -w " & quoted form of (thePath & "%f.txt" as text) & "; open " & outputFiles
end run
```